# Validation on textbox using jquery for pan Number format

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I have to add Pan no in my website Application but i have to use jquery for validation so that first 5 no. should be alphabet then 4 no. should be numeric and the last Questions should be alphabet.

```
$('#txtPANNumber').keypress(function (event) { 
var key = event.which; 
var esc = (key == 127 || key == 8 || key == 0 || key == 46); 
//alert(key); 
//var nor = $("#txtPANNumber").mask("aaaaa9999a"); 
var regExp = /[a-zA-z]{5}\d{4}[a-zA-Z]{1}/; 
var txtpan = $(this).val(); 
if (txtpan.length < 10 ) { 
 if( txtpan.match( regExp) ){ 
  //event.preventDefault(); 
 } 
} else { event.preventDefault(); } });
```

Please provide some solutions

Comment: give a sample of pan no

Answer (score 4):

This will do

```
/[a-zA-z]{5}\d{4}[a-zA-Z]{1}/
```

Check [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/yU7jA4/1)

Code

```
$('#txtPANNumber').change(function (event) {     
 var regExp = /[a-zA-z]{5}\d{4}[a-zA-Z]{1}/; 
 var txtpan = $(this).val(); 
 if (txtpan.length == 10 ) { 
  if( txtpan.match(regExp) ){ 
   alert('PAN match found');
  }
  else {
   alert(Not a valid PAN number);
   event.preventDefault(); 
  } 
 } 
 else { 
       alert('Please enter 10 digits for a valid PAN number');
       event.preventDefault(); 
 } 

});
```

Comment: **code in jquery**    '$('#txtPANNumber').keypress(function (event) {
      var key = event.which;
      var esc = (key == 127 || key == 8 || key == 0 || key == 46);
        //alert(key);
        //var nor = $("#txtPANNumber").mask("aaaaa9999a");
        var regExp = /[a-zA-z]{5}\d{4}[a-zA-Z]{1}/;
        var txtpan = $(this).val();
        if (txtpan.length < 10 ) {
            if( txtpan.match( regExp) ){
                //event.preventDefault();
            }
          
        }
        
        else {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });'

Comment: here is the code ....it is not putting any validation when i am entering the PAN Number

Comment: change the event from keypress to change

Comment: also since you are entering 10 digits change condition `txtpan.length < 10` to txtpan.length == 10

Comment: Thanks for your try but nothing happens , it is not validating when i entered the input

Comment: add alert messages in if .. else condition to check which part is getting executed.. check edit and tell what is the alert message

Comment: Nothing Happened...your code doesn't work.. . but in my previous code i have added alert message and i got to know that **if( txtpan.match(regExp) )**  is not correct because else condition alert is running

Comment: Actually Problem is in RegExp . I have Checked my RegExp online and i got to know the error **(Error: No Capturing Groups added )** and it get corrected after adding it.....But Thanks a Lot !!!!!! **Mudassir** for your great efforts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below regex to validate input for PAN.

```
[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}
```

Function for JS :

```
function validatePAN(pan){ 
    var regex = /[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}$/; 
    return regex.test(pan); 
}
```

But don't rely only on JS validation, as JS validation can easily disabled from client side. Put a check on server side as well for inputs.

Also you need to change your if condition to something like below :

```
if(length == 10)
```

Comment: **code in jquery**    '$('#txtPANNumber').keypress(function (event) {
      var key = event.which;
      var esc = (key == 127 || key == 8 || key == 0 || key == 46);
        //alert(key);
        //var nor = $("#txtPANNumber").mask("aaaaa9999a");
        var regExp = /[a-zA-z]{5}\d{4}[a-zA-Z]{1}/;
        var txtpan = $(this).val();
        if (txtpan.length < 10 ) {
            if( txtpan.match( regExp) ){
                //event.preventDefault();
            }
          
        }
        
        else {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });'

Comment: No Error found in console